# Inheritance of variables not working in terraform

Tags: terraform

For a terraform project I have the following folder structure:

```
- variables.tf
- cloudsql
    - variables.tf
    - main.tf
```

In the high-level variables.tf file I have defined:

```
variable "availability_type" {
  default = {
    prod = "REGIONAL"
    dev  = "ZONAL"
}
```

where prod and dev refer to production and dev workspaces.

In the cloudsql specific level variables.tf I have defined:

```
variable "availability_type" {
  type = "map"
}
```

Finally in main.tf (under cloudsql) I use the variable

```
availability_type = "${var.availability_type[terraform.workspace]}"
```

However, this leads to

```
module.cloudsql.google_sql_database_instance.master: key "default" does not exist in map var.availability_type in:

${var.availability_type[terraform.workspace]}
```

Why does the cloudsql not inherit the variables?

Comment: Because your current workspace is `default` and not `prod` or `dev`. You can confirm this with the `terraform workspace list` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out correctly by Matt Schuchard the workspace was default. Running

```
terraform workspace select dev
```

beforehand resolved the issue.